# s3.upload does not do anything

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, amazon-s3, aws-lambda

```
const params = {
  Bucket: 'static.lore.com',
  Key:`someKey.json`,
  ContentType: 'application/json',
  Body: JSON.stringify(bodyJSON),
};

console.info(`Post ${postMetaData.id} uploading`);
const response = await s3.upload(params).promise();
console.info(`Post ${postMetaData.id} uploaded successfully`, response);
```

I tried like 100 different stuff, when lambda get to this point it shows me the post uploading log
and then it goes dark, and does no do anything else until timeout kill the lambda.

Everything work locally Y had search a lot off example and i still stuck, please help.

Comment: What gets logged as a response?

Comment: also what do cloudtrail entries tell ? 
how about tracing to know what is happening using X-Ray 
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/xray/latest/devguide/xray-sdk-nodejs-awssdkclients.html

Comment: just to help others. lamba inside a vpc do not see S3. you have make a and endpoint from your vpc to s3. in VPC Endpoint. think of it as a patch to access from your VPC to S3 services. or get lamba out of the VPC. thanks you aliwinski an purna for the attention.

Comment: @MarioRedonavich I'm facing the same error. Could you answer your own question with the solution?